# How do I programmatically remove a certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authorities?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, digital-certificate, certificate-authority

I need to be able to remove a specific certificate from each PC in my organization. Yes, I could go seat-to-seat, but I have until Thursday to pull it off, and I don't have the manpower to go seat-to-seat.

Is there a programmatic way of doing this using C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to crank out any C# - take a look at [`certmgr.exe /del`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28VS.80%29.aspx).

If you really *do* want to write some C# today to do this, then take a look at [`X509Store.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.remove.aspx).

Comment: I'm looking at those pages. Unfortunately, they don't tell me how to access (if at all) "trusted Root Certification Authorities". I can't see how to get to that store.

Comment: The Trusted Root Certification Authorities store is just called "root". Or are you saying you having a "permission denied" problem?

Comment: Nope.. I didn't know it was called ROOT. That solved everything. It's the little details that kill you.

Answer (score 3):

There's an example in MSDN ([click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.openflags(VS.80).aspx))

I think the example is self-explanatory, but here's the excerpt:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO;

public class X509store2
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        //Create new X509 store called teststore from the local certificate store.
        X509Store store = new X509Store ("ROOT", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open (OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        ...

        store.Remove (certificate1);
        store.RemoveRange (collection);

        ...

        //Close the store.
        store.Close ();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Question is looking to remove it from the Trusted Root Cert store.