# physical path for personal certificate store

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This seens to be a non frequent topic because I can´t find any reference of this.

Digital Certificates are stored in stores.

As you can see here...

[How do I programmatically remove a certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authorities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652206/how-do-i-programmatically-remove-a-certificate-in-trusted-root-certification-aut)

Where are stored the personal digital certificate?
The store name is My as we can see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx

But I need to find the location of the file itself to manipulate the certificate programatically.

**Edit**

I am also trying to print my cert name and path this way but I get nothing printed:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
X509Certificate2Collection storecollection = 
      (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

Console.WriteLine("Store name: {0}", store.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Store location: {0}", store.Location);
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine("certificate name: {0}",x509.Subject);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no physical files for individual certificates as far as I know.

On second question: you are missing `Open` call like `store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);`. See complete sample on MSDN [X509Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Alexei. But if there is no physical path, how can I remove progamatically a certificate? Here Microsoft says: X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2 ("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer"); ... store.Remove (certificate1); How should I point to my certificate?

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo, I believe ones from `store.Certificates` are fine to call `Remove` with. Like `store.Remove(store.Certificates.First());`